# Core Data Entities Attributes and Relationship, I think I foobared

Tags: ios, core-data

Alright, so my app is moving along, I am able to create accounts, and login with the newly created accounts.  I also have a root account which can display a list of all the accounts.  In the process of developing this application I have created 25 accounts on the simulator (don't ask).  So the next logical step for me was to implement a function to delete these accounts.  Well I started looking at things and realized this is going to be a lot more difficult than originally planed.  At first I thought I could do a fetch request and delete the username and all the data associated with it would be deleted.  I soon realized I never setup a relationship between the attributes in my entity.

So I know what your thinking, (nuke all objects in the Core Data DB).  I am not opposed to doing that, but I have stored passwords / pins for user accounts in the keychain.  So I am not sure if I delete all the objects in the Core Data DB then the pin's created with the user account are in keychain limbo somewhere.  I have a method for deleting / removing the keychain for an account but it requires a username to be associated with it (that's why I am partially opposed to nuking everything).

So before I go any further and create any more accounts or put this thing in the wild (still have a lot of developing to do) **what's the best way to associate the attributes together, i.e. create a relationship between them?**  As it stands, I have one entity named **Account** and within that entity I have 4 attributes: *credit*, *email*, *phoneNumber*, *username*.  I have a form where the user creates a username, inputs a pin, email, and phonenumber.  I would like to be able to delete all these attributes just by deleting the username, so I guess there's gotta be some sort relationship setup.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am now able to delete the user accounts on the Simulator thanks to the following code, FWIW when I delete an account it also deletes the attributes associated with the account (bonus).  I guess the attributes are part of the object that is getting deleted (not sure).  But this is the functionality I was looking for.

```
- (IBAction)deleteAccount:(id)sender {

// TODO - implement method / code to delete a user account

// CORE DATA
// setup up the fetch request
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

// define our table / entity to use
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Account" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

// Fetch the records and handle an error
NSError *error;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:& error] mutableCopy];

if (!mutableFetchResults) {
    // handle error.
    // should advise user to restart
}

// compare text field text / string with results in an array
for (Account *anAccount in mutableFetchResults) {
    if([anAccount.username isEqualToString:self.tfDeleteAccount.text]) {
        NSLog(@"username found.");

        // delete keychain for account
        [anAccount prepareForDeletion];

        // delete account object
        [_managedObjectContext deleteObject:anAccount];

        // save the managed object context
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"error %@", error);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand the concept of Core Data attributes and entities. After talking with you in chat you have 1 entity which is **Account** and you just need to delete that object from the entity.

You do this by doing the below

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Account" inManagedObjectContext:[[CoreDataHelper sharedInstance] managedObjectContext]];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username == %@", usernameString];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
Account *account = (Account*) [[[[CoreDataHelper sharedInstance] managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] objectAtIndex:0];

[[[CoreDataHelper sharedInstance] managedObjectContext] deleteObject:account];
[[[CoreDataHelper sharedInstance] managedObjectContext] processPendingChanges];
```

Note that your CoreData context may be different.

By doing the above, this will delete the **Account** object with the attributes (*credit, email, phoneNumber, username*).

Comment: I am not trying to remove the Core Data entity from the Core Data DB, I just want to select a username stored in the Core Data DB, and delete the associated information with it.

If I fetch the usernames in the Core Data DB, and put them in an Array.  I want to delete one username from the array.  I would also like to delete the information associated with the username.  That is why I was asking about relationships.  If I delete an account I don't want to have to fetch the username, email, and phonenumber separately to delete all the attribues associated with a username.

Comment: @Chris like I said I don't think you are understanding the concept of core data. Use a predicate to filter the Accounts based on a username.  Then take that object and delete it.

Comment: @Chris I have modified the above code to show you the basic idea of how to get the object.